# Meteor update - which url it uses?

Tags: meteor, proxy, package

Is there a global url where meteor is trying to access when we use the command `meteor update` ?

I need to configure some url for my proxy and I need to specify some url to my network administrator.

I probably need to add the github url of course and "packages.meteor.com". Is there anything else ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It most likely hits https://install.meteor.com. You'd probably be fine with meteor.com.